# Find type of $f(x)$ problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

My teacher gaves us an excersise and i need help because i cant solve it. It's an antiderivative where i need to calculate the f type.

$$f'(x)=f(x){(x+1)^2\over(x+1)},$$
for $x>0$, $f(0)=1$.

Sorry for my english. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the $\dfrac{(x+1)^2}{x+1}$ ?

Comment: i don't know. i had that problem too. he said it's better to avoid simplification

Comment: Perhaps he had some special method in mind other than integrating between $0$ and $t$ both sides of the equation $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=x+1$$

Comment: Ok. But if f(x)=<0 ?

Comment: @TakisOmegas Why does that matter?

Comment: f.e if f(x)=0 i can't devide with it.

I have to find f. So it will be:

(ln|f(x)|)'=(x^2/2+x)' ?

Comment: oohhh you have a homogeneous first order differential equation here. Do you know how to solve one of those?

Answer (score 0):

You should write it differently: $$\frac {f'(x)}{f(x)} ={(x+1)^2\over(x+1)}$$ and remember the derivative of $$ log f(x) $$